# Deleting XMLList data, after certain element

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, xmllist

Basically, since XMLList are similar to Arrays in many ways, I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
XMLList.length = 10;
```

I know this is not possible because 'length' in XMLList is not a property but is a method. Hence is something like a get method without a set method. Only `XMLList.length()` would work.

But is there a workaround. An easier one.

I know this can be done with loops or by converting the XMLList to Array, cutting off and converting it back to XMLList. I'd like to know if there's an easier way.

Comment: To get only the top 10 values in the xmllist ;D

Comment: And you need that because ...? And also: How is the list created?

Comment: I wanted to do exactly what alxx did below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (xmlList.length() > 10)
{
    delete(xmlList[10]);
}
```